# Adding up margin+10 per child jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I have a dynamic website which my client can add up blocks to which got a scroll function on it but I need the blocks to get a `margin-top: 10;` added per class like:

```
.li-1 { margin-top:0; }

.li-2 { margin-top: 10px; }

.li-3 { margin-top: 20px }

.li-4 { margin-top: 30px }
```

This is my trial code: http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uj5/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u8Uj5/10/ like this?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like that

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uj5/11/)

```
$( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).css("margin-top", index * 10 + "px")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `each` to loop over all the elements, add the margin using the `index` of the element.

```js
$('div').each(function(i) {
  $(this).css('margin-top', (i * 10) + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>-------------------------

<h2> I want it like this but then dynamic: </h2>

<div class="s">1</div>
<div class="p">2</div>
<div class="a">3</div>
<div class="n">4</div>
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/u8Uj5/10/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try:

```
var myMargin = 0; //initial value

$( "div" ).each(function() {
    $(this).css("margin-top", myMargin + "px");
    myMargin += 10; //set your indention whatever you need
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Uj5/12/)